# Delaying an action

Tags: swift, ios7

I have UIView A and UIView B. A is a subview of a scrollView along with siblings subviews C-Z. B has a UILongPressGestureRecognizer and can be dragged around. If B is dragged inside A or C-Z I have function that does something. However, I want that function to go off only when B has been inside A for 1 second. If B is not inside A after that second I don't want anything to happen. How can I achieve this? I've already tried using an NSTimer.

```
timer = NSTimer()
timer.scheduledTimerWithInterval(1.0,target:self,  #selector(fireMethod),userInfo:nil, repeats:Yes)
```

It seemed to work once, but after that first time, it never worked again.

Comment: What would _you_ suggest? Also, did you ask the [rubber ducky](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/)? It's important to describe how you attempted to solve the problem and what obstacles you encountered.

Comment: @paulvs thank you for the article! I'll work on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Swift 3.0

```
func delayWithSeconds(_ seconds: Double, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) { 
        completion()
    }
}
```

Usage

```
delayWithSeconds(1) {
   //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a delay function like so

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {

    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time( DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)


}
```

Then in your `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` call the function as so

```
self.delay(1)
{
  //code here
}
```

Comment: This does not address how to make sure that one view stays inside the other view for 1 second.

Comment: add it to your if statement for if it gets added in so if View B is in for 1 second then delay whatever the function will be and if it is not in the View then call the function straight away

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourAction:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.3];//give delay asper your requirement.

-(void)yourAction
{
//your reuire code after delay.
}
```